# How to debug "operator expected" in this Prolog program?

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to run a query for a family tree but when I enter all the information, I'm getting a syntax error: operator expected. I'm new to Prolog.

domains

```
name=symbol
```

predicates

```
 parent(name,name)
 female(name)
 male(name)
 sister(name,name)
 son(name,name)
 father(name)
 grandmother(name)
```

clauses

```
female(stella).
female(lizzy).
female(emily).
female(mia).
female(alice).

male(hubert).
male(ben).
male(john).
male(danny).
male(sam).

 parent(stella,ben).
 parent(stella,mia).
 parent(hubert,ben).
 parent(hubert,mia).
 parent(lizzy,emily).
 parent(lizzy,john).
 parent(ben,emily).
 parent(ben,john).
 parent(mia,sam).
 parent(mia,alice).
 parent(danny,sam).
 parent(danny,alice).
 sister(X,Y):-female(X),parent(Par,X),parent(Par,Y),X\==XY.
 son(X,Y):-parent(Z,X),parent(Z,Y),male(X),X\==Y.
 father(X,Y):-parent(X,Y),male(X).
 grandmother(X,Y):-parent(X,Y),female(X)
```

Comment: Without seeing the _actual_ error we probably can't be too helpful, but this looks like Visual Prolog syntax being entered into an ISO-ish Prolog such as SWI. Delete your "domains" and "predicates" and maybe you'll have better luck.

Comment: Can you please edit the title describing the exact problem "I'm not quite sure what to do" is not really a good title.

Comment: As for your file, you forgot a dot (`.`) at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems here:

1. you forgot a dot (`.`) at the end rhat signals the end of the clause; and
2. this is not really an error, but you write `X\==XY` in the `sister/2` clause, since `XY` is a new variable, this will *always* succeed.

There is also a *semantical* problem with the `grandmother/2` predicate: right now it defines a "mother" predicate. I leave this as an exercise.

I also advise to reformat your code (Prolog does not charge you per line, and it makes it more clear where a clause ends and what it does).

```
sister(X,Y) :-
    female(X),
    parent(Par,X),
    parent(Par,Y),
    X \== Y.

son(X,Y) :-
    parent(Z,X),
    parent(Z,Y),
    male(X),
    X \== Y.

father(X,Y) :-
    parent(X,Y),
    male(X).

grandmother(X,Y) :-
    parent(X,Y),
    female(X).
```